Gradle build failed after a pull request
I'm trying to do a pull request on github, but when I push all from git, the pull request says that gradle build failed. That are the details:
Run ./gradlew build
Downloading https......
...........10%............20%............30%............40%............50%............60%...........70%............80%............90%............100%
Welcome to Gradle 8.0.2!
Here are the highlights of this release:

Improvements to the Kotlin DSL
Fine-grained parallelism from the first build with configuration cache
Configurable Gradle user home cache cleanup

Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

Task :compileJava FAILED
1 actionable task: 1 executed
/home/runner/work/progetto-blum/progetto-blum/src/main/java/it/uniba/app/Tavoliere.java:1: error: illegal character: '\ufeff'
﻿package it.uniba.app;
^
/home/runner/work/progetto-blum/progetto-blum/src/main/java/it/uniba/app/Tavoliere.java:1: error: class, interface, enum, or record expected
﻿package it.uniba.app;
^
2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.


Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.

BUILD FAILED in 18s
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
Anyone know how to resolve this problem? Or what this problem means?

/home/runner/work/progetto-blum/progetto-blum/src/main/java/it/uniba/app/Tavoliere.java:1: error: illegal character: '\ufeff' package it.uniba.app; ^ is the original error. Seems to be a Unicode character at the start of that file. Second error is caused by the first error confusing the parser, and will be fixed if the first error is. \ufeff is a zero width non-breaking space, so unless you did that yourself I'd look into a different file editor.

@l3l_aze thanks for your reply. I use Intellij and I can't find any characters at the beginning of the file. Any suggestions? The same error is also given when I pull different files

They're zero-width so they won't be visible without somehow being converted to visible characters (HTML encoding, hex view of file, etc), and the easiest way to find them is to use the arrow keys and notice when it doesn't move after a press. Are the different files this also happens with from this same repo or the same person who made the most recent commits on this same repo? If so, it may be an issue on their end. If not, then it's probably your end.
